# Filling SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms

I am running a SQLQuery that takes roughly 45 seconds to run and display results.  I am using `Task<DataSet>` to populate two drop downs on my page.  Well the 1st drop down populates fine (the query is completed in about 2 seconds), the second it seems that the `adapter.Fill(dataSet)` is not waiting on the query to complete before it begins to fill the drop down with a null dataset.  What should I alter so that the code execution halts until the query executes completely?

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[]
{
  One("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"),
  Two("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"),
}, tasks =>
{
  try
  {
    this.ddl1.DataSource = tasks[0].Result.Tables[0];
    this.ddl1.DataTextField = "One";
    this.ddl1.DataValueField = "ID";
    this.ddl1.DataBind();
    int indexOfLastItem = this.ddl1.Items.Count - 1;
    this.ddl1.SelectedIndex = indexOfLastItem;
    ddl2.DataSource = tasks[1].Result.Tables[0];
    this.ddl2.DataTextField = "Two";
    this.ddl2.DataValueField = "ID";
    this.ddl2.DataBind();
    this.ddl2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(Constants.All, Constants.All));
  }
  catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> One(string databaseConnection)
{
  return FillDS("Select * from activeemployees", databaseConnection);
}
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> Two(string databaseConnection)
{
  return FillDS("Select * from mastersalesdatabase", databaseConnection);
}
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> FillDS(string sqlQuery, string connectionString)
{
  try
  {
    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, connectionString))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        return dataSet;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
}
```

My query `Select * from activeemployees` completes in about 2 seconds and populates fine, my query `Select * from mastersalesdatabase` takes roughly 45 seconds and it seems the code just moves on w/o a delay to let the query execute to completion.

Comment: Do you need *all* the data from that table? 45 seconds is quite a while for a query that's running in a web application instead of in some background process.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need all the data that the query returns.

Comment: In that case, you should look into *why* it's taking 45 seconds for such a simple query. Also, if you're going to use Tasks, then you should look into TAP pattern and the async/await keywords. Also, special care must be taken with async in Web Forms, described by Microsoft [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

Comment: `ddl2.DataSource = tasks[0].Result.Tables[0];` Should that be `ddl2.DataSource = tasks[1].Result.Tables[0];` ?

Comment: @MaxSorin - good catch.  I updated my post.  I changed it to 0 as I commented out the first one to see if ddl2 would populate w/o the call to populate ddl1, obviously no such mustard.

Comment: @mason - the long running query is querying a view with 5.647 rows.

Comment: And you need all five thousand rows in a single drop down list? That sounds like a horrible user experience. If there's a lot of things to choose from, then an auto complete textbox is much more appropriate.

Comment: I do not need all 5K - I just added in Select Distinct() and now it returns just under 400 results, but still takes about 40 seconds to complete.

Comment: Using select distinct is a code smell and means that your table design is probably bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to do async to retrieve data into a datatable, it should look more like this:

```
public static async Task<DataTable> GetDataTableAsync(string connectionString, SqlCommand command)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (var dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Load(dataReader);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice there's no need for a dataset.

Then in WebForms, we have to handle async code differently.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(DoWorkAsync));
}

private async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    ActiveEmployeesDropDownList.DataSource = GetDataTableAsync(databaseConnection, new SqlCommand("select * from activeemployees"));
    ActiveEmployeesDropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

Notice I renamed the control from `ddl1` to `ActiveEmployeesDropDownList` because `ddl1` is a horrible name. Your names should have semantic meaning.

You'll need to add the `async=true` attribute to your page [according to MSDN](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

And you should also fix your query to not take 45 seconds, but that's a separate question entirely.